# Why proximal muscle weakness improves in Lambert- Eaton syndrome with isometric contraction?

Tags: muscle, pathophysiology

Lambert Eaton has antibodies to presynaptic calcium VGC(voltage gated channel).
So how does doing an isometric (or any other type of contraction) will improve weakness, what will be pathophysiology?

Does it involve excess release of calcium due to over stimulation externally by high frequency of single fibres which ultimately include compound muscle action potential?

source of info-

> https://www.cancertherapyadvisor.com/home/decision-support-in-medicine/hospital-medicine/lambert-eaton-myasthenic-syndrome-eaton-lambert-syndrome/

[image]